# Routes error for entity `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.`

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

In a DXA 1.7 .NET web application I have several custom DXA modules. After I moved a few models, views and controllers from one module to the other I got this routes error for one of the entities.

This shows up in the browser

```
A problem occurred while rendering this section
No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
```

The log recorded this error

```
    2017-08-17 08:54:33,329 [6] ERROR - No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
    System.InvalidOperationException: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues)
       at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntity(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, EntityModel entity, Int32 containerSize)
       at Sdl.Web.Mvc.Html.HtmlHelperExtensions.DxaEntities(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, Int32 containerSize)
       at ASP.........._MainSide_cshtml.Execute() in .........MainSide.cshtml:line 3
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
       at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
       at RazorGenerator.Mvc.PrecompiledMvcView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
```

What could cause this error?

Comment: Are you able to compile the webapplication after moving the items?

Comment: Yes, I can compile the web application, if it would not compile I could not run it to get this error ;)

Comment: Have you updated the metadata fields of the Component Templates that use those views/controllers so they point to the correct module, and are they republished correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `RegisterArea()` method of my module registration class (the one which extends `BaseAreaRegistration`), I did not call base.RegisterArea().

At the same time for an experiment the RegisterAllViewModels() of the module was called in a different way. Hence the registration of views and viewmodels worked fine, but the module's controllers did not work.

It appears that [BaseAreaRegistration.RegisterArea()](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Configuration/BaseAreaRegistration.cs) does register a default entity route. I do not know what exactly it does, but without it your custom controllers don't work.

Answer (score 0):

For a .NET MVC Web application, Routes are registered in `applictation_start` method. Can you check whether you have these lines available in your web application's `global.asax.cs` file -> `application_start` method,

```
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
```

verify that you have not modified the `RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)` in the DXA web application which might also causes issues

Comment: Thanks for the hint but this was not the issue in my case.